# обучение lsfusion

Tags: lsfusion

Начал изучать lsFusion по официальной документации. Не со всем получается разобраться. Может есть более понятные варианты изучения, например тьюториалы какие?

Answer (score 2):

Есть вот такая книга, можно попробовать изучать с её помощью
https://lsfusion.org/ru/ed_materials

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/907677)

Comment: @Amgarak, а как по-вашему стоило оформить этот ответ? Здесь кроме ссылки ничего и не надо.